# map "Ñ" to ":" in vim

Tags: vim, configuration, keyboard-shortcuts, key-mapping

I want map the key <kbd>Ñ</kbd> (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>ñ</kbd>) to <kbd>:</kbd> in the normal mode of vim.

I've searched vim configs with Ntilde but I've found nothing. Any idea?.

Comment: Which is the normal mode? Command mode or insert mode?

Comment: What is wrong with `nmap Ñ :` ?

Comment: @Marco thanks, your suggestion works perfect :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marco suggested `nmap Ñ :` and it works perfect.